# Why does increasing the concentration of an electrolyte decrease the mass deposited when electroplating?

Tags: electrochemistry, electroplating

I am in the process of writing a lab where the manipulated variable is the concentration of the electrolyte (zinc sulfate heptahydrate) and the responding variable is the mass of zinc deposited on a copper cathode. I electroplated each manipulation at a constant current. Hence, I found that as the concentration increases, the voltage and the mass deposited decreased.

I have researched a lot and have not found an explanation to why mass deposited decreases when current is controlled. Please help if possible!

Comment: Did you see zinc collected at the bottom of the beaker?

Comment: I did observe a few small zinc sheddings in the electrolyte solution after electroplating. 

However, my procedure involved creating a concentrated 1.0 mol/L solution and diluting it for my manipulations with smaller concentrations. Does this impact the relationship?

Comment: Depositing Zinc metal requires 0.76 V.  It may be possible that too concentrated an electrolyte solution was too conductive to have a large enough voltage difference near the cathode.  So you may try various concentrations and also experiment along the axis of variable voltage.  This work should yield an excellent report and graphs even if it does not succeed.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni How exactly would a too conductive solution cause a lower faradaic efficiency? My guess would be these sheddings are significant or you're having a higher partial current for the HER, how exactly a high ZnSO4 causes this to happen I am not sure of.

Comment: Just a gut feeling.  "Constant current".  V = IR.  I hope it's DC.  If so, the solution (and apparatus) may be simply grounding the current.  I would increase voltage.  Using a DC transformer (like those used for heating mantles) may help.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! I will definitely consider them in my lab writeup.